# unable to thread multiple external scripts in python interpreter using stdin

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, stdin, popen

I have the following scripts
The perl script(fasta.pl) takes an input file(abc) and gives string.

```
 $ ./fasta.pl abc.txt
```

I first tried

```
p1= subprocess.Popen(["./pdb_fasta.pl","abc.txt"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE);
```

then I confirmed that p1 is a file object

```
>>> type(p1.stdout)
<type 'file'>
```

I have another script, count.py that takes a file as input

```
$ ./count.py p1.stdout
```

now when I try to use the p1.stdout for this script, I get error. I tried two different methods
first one

```
p2= subprocess.Popen(["./count_aa.py",p1.stdout],stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()
```

and the error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 595, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1106, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings
```

second method: Here the error is because the script count_aa.py needs a file as an argument and stdin is not providing.

```
>>> p2= subprocess.Popen(["./count_aa.py"],stdin=p1.stdout,stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./count_aa.py", line 4, in <module>
    fil=open(sys.argv[1],'r').read()
IndexError: list index out of range
>>>
```

I was thinking on this line to achieve the desired result where I pass the output from one child process as input to another. But this does not work as explained above.

```
p1= subprocess.Popen(["./pdb_fasta.pl","abc.txt"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2= subprocess.Popen(["./count_aa.py"],stdin=p1.stdout,stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()
```

can some explain the mistakes here and give an example where stdin could be useful or how to use in this scenario. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last code is equivalent to following shell command.

```
./pdb_fasta.pl abc.txt | ./count_aa.py
```

To make your last code to work, change `count_aa.py` to get input from stdin. For example:

```
import sys

n = 0
for line in sys.stdin:
    n += 1
print(n)
```

Comment: sorry,I do not understand,can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: Your `count_aa.py` program access to sys.argv[1] which is not passed when called as `subprocess.Popen(["./count_aa.py"],stdin=p1.stdout,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`. In this case, you should read from stdin.

Comment: Thanks falsteru, for clarification, isnt stdin as same as sys.argv[1] in this case. if not what is the difference? or how to use stdin ( file object?) effectively?

Comment: `sys.argv[1] != sys.stdin`. You cannot pass stdin as command line argument.